# Question on Wiring for a new light fixture

Tags: wiring, led

I am replacing a old florescent light with a LED.

I have two light switches that control the light. In the wiring box, there are two white, two red, two black and one ground/copper wire. I did not take a picture prior to undoing the wiring on the old light. The two black wires as shown were capped as it. I only removed the white, red and ground wire from the old light as shown.

Based on the new light (pic) I am looking for thoughts in wiring this led correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How were the wires connected in the box to the old light before you took it down. ?

Comment: "*I have tried a few logical attempts*" **You need to tell us what you have done and add as much info as possible**.

Comment: It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Are there any half-switched outlets that are controlled by the same switch that controls that light?